# Facebook Video Player Code

Tags: facebook, github, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I believe that I have found a bug in Facebook's video player, and to configure and correct that I need the source code for the video player or its plug-in code, but I was unable to find it on Github or anywhere else.

Please help me getting the code, or post any relevant links that would help me with that.

Comment: What video player and why do you think you would get the code for it?

Comment: @WizKid , I am referring to the HTML5 video player which fb uses to display videos in the web news feed.

Comment: Why would you get the code for that?

Comment: @WizKid because it might be open source!

Comment: It is not open source

Answer (score 1):

All facebook GitHub repositories are at [`github.com/facebook`](https://github.com/facebook?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=)

You have more at [`facebook.github.com`](https://facebook.github.com/), which actually redirects to [`code.facebook.com`](https://code.facebook.com/)

If you don't see the sources there, the project itself is either not publicly available or is not directly maintained by Facebook.